# Can not return to same page after click on cancel button while using Angular.js pagination

Tags: angularjs, pagination, dirpagination

I have one issue.Here i need to return back to the same page while using pagination in Angular.js.Let me to explain the code and scenario.

```
<div class="row" ng-show="showForm">
  <form name="billdata" id="billdata"  enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
         <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-12">
          <span class="input-group-addon ndrftextwidth text-right oditek-form" style="width:180px">Restaurant Name :</span>
      <input type="text" name="colgname1" id="colgname1" class="form-control oditek-form" placeholder="Add  Name" ng-model="name" ng-keypress="clearField('colgname1');"  maxlength="50">
    </div>
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-red" ng-click="clearCustomerInfoData();"  id="addProfileData" ng-value="ClearbuttonName" ng-show="showCancel"/>
   </form>
</div>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Edit</th>
     <th>Remove</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody id="detailsstockid">
<tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter:searchProduct.rest_name | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">

<td >
 <a ui-sref="dashboard.customer.view">
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Edit' ng-click="editProductViewData(cus.member_id);">  
</a>
</td>
 <td>
<a ui-sref="dashboard.customer.view">
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-red' value='Delete' ng-click="deleteProductInfoData(cus.member_id);" >  
</a>
</td>
</tr>   
</tbody>
</table>
 <div class="pull-right">
<dir-pagination-controls  max-size="5"  direction-links="true"  boundary-links="true" >
 </dir-pagination-controls>
</div>
```

Here i am used `dir-paginate` for pagination .suppose user is in `3` page and when clicked on the `edit` button the form will open which code is given below.

```
$scope.editProductViewData=function(memberid){
    $scope.showForm=true;
    $scope.ClearbuttonName="Cancel";
    $scope.showCancel=true;
}
```

But i am clicking in `Cancel` button inside form in recent case it is returning to the `1st` page.the code is given below.

```
$scope.clearCustomerInfoData=function(){
        $state.go('dashboard.customer.view',{}, { reload: true });
}
```

my config file is given below.

```
var Admin=angular.module('Spesh',['ui.router', '720kb.datepicker','ngMessages','ngCapsLock','ui.bootstrap','ngFileUpload','angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
Admin.run(function($rootScope, $state) {
      $rootScope.$state = $state;
    });
Admin.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    .state('dashboard', { /* This state defines The root admin login page. */
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'adminController'
        })
      .state('dashboard.customer', { 
        url: '/customer',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/customer.html',
        controller: 'adminCustomerController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.customer.new', { 
        url: '/new',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/customerNew.html',
        controller: 'adminCustomerNewController'
        })
        .state('dashboard.customer.view', { 
        url: '/view',
        templateUrl: 'dashboardview/customerView.html',
        controller: 'adminCustomerViewController'
        })
})
```

Here i need suppose user is in `3rd` page and clicked on edit button then the form opened .When user will click on `Cancel` button it should come back to that `3rd` page not 1st page.Please help me.

Comment: it will help us if you can provide how you handle your dashboard.customer.view route and dir-pagination-controls's config to set page number.

Comment: @krish ; i have updated my post and attached the config file.Please check this.

Answer (score 0):

I think, The value of current page is updating.
Please give more info about your controller.

OR apply `$watch` function in the `$scope.currentPage`.

because it might be set `$scope.currentPage = 1`

Comment: i think ,i have already post the required info. Here suppose the user is in 3rd page and clicked on edit button then the form will open.When user will click on cancel button it should come back to that 3rd page which is not happening.Please check my updated post.